# How do I return an id string instead of a _bsontype with NestJS Serialization

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

When using

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
```

like it is explained in the Documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization)

I get the desired filtered result, however while using mongodb the id is formatted in `_bsontype` instead of a normal `string` like it used to be without the interceptor like this:

```
{
    "id": {
        "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
        "id": {
            "0": 92,
            "1": 108,
            "2": 182,
            "3": 85,
            "4": 185,
            "5": 20,
            "6": 221,
            "7": 12,
            "8": 56,
            "9": 66,
            "10": 131,
            "11": 172
        }
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-02-20T02:07:17.895Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-02-20T02:07:17.895Z",
    "firstName": "The First Name",
    "lastName": "The Last Name",
    "email": "giberish@gmail.com"
}
```

How can I convert it back to a normal id string like this?

```
{
    "id": "5c6cb655b914dd0c384283ac",
    "createdAt": "2019-02-20T02:07:17.895Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-02-20T02:07:17.895Z",
    "firstName": "The First Name",
    "lastName": "The Last Name",
    "email": "giberish@gmail.com"
    "password": "okthen"
}
```

Comment: It might help to lift the relevant repro steps from the link into your question directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use class-transformer's `@Transform()` with the option `toPlainOnly`:

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.toString(), { toPlainOnly: true })
  _id: ObjectID;
```

The `ClassSerializerInterceptor` internally uses class-transformer's `classToPlain()` method.

Comment: The answer returns [Object Object] for me. I have to use `@Transform(({value}) => value.toString(), { toPlainOnly: true })`

Comment: @webHasan Thanks for your comment, I have updated the answer. The signature has changed with version 0.3.2, see changelog: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/v0.5.1/CHANGELOG.md#032-breaking-change---2021-01-14